# How do you wait for user input in a do loop?

Tags: vb.net

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzCHN.jpg

The program I am trying to make is a text-based game.

The player inputs commands and the inputs are displayed in a list box, along with the different "rooms"

There is a set spawnpoint which is a boolean statement that is true until a command is inputted.

For example, if "n" is inputted, a second boolean "spawnpointN" is true and the original spawn point is false.

Before the loop iterates once, I want it to wait for user input.

How do I get the loop to pause?

```
Public Class frmMain

    Const north As String = "n"
    Const east As String = "e"
    Const west As String = "w"
    Const south As String = "s"
    Dim input As String

    Dim finished As Boolean = False
    Dim spawnpoint As Boolean = True
    Dim spawnpointN As Boolean = False
    Dim spawnpointE As Boolean = False
    Dim spawnpointW As Boolean = False
    Dim spawnpointS As Boolean = False

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AcceptButton = btnEnter
        Do
            If spawnpoint = True Then
                Me.lstDisplay.Items.Add("You awake in a room of darkness.")

                If Me.input = north Then
                    spawnpointN = True
                    spawnpoint = False
                End If

                If Me.input = east Then
                    spawnpointE = True
                    spawnpoint = False
                End If

                If Me.input = south Then
                    spawnpointS = True
                    spawnpoint = False
                End If

                If Me.input = west Then
                    spawnpointW = True
                    spawnpoint = False
                End If

            End If

            If spawnpointN = True Then
                lstDisplay.Items.Add("Test")
                If Me.input = south Then
                    Me.spawnpoint = True
                    Me.spawnpointN = False
                End If
            End If
            If input = "end" Then
                finished = True
            End If

        Loop Until finished = True

        If finished = True Then
            lstDisplay.Items.Add("You have finished my game!")

        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
        Dim input As String = Me.txtInput.Text
        Me.lstDisplay.Items.Add(input)
        Me.txtInput.Clear()
        lstDisplay.TopIndex = lstDisplay.Items.Count - 1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Right now, my code doesn't even run.

Comment: Please always provide the error message. Otherwise it will be difficult or impossible to help you.

Comment: When I press run, nothing happens. It is just stuck at this https://imgur.com/yYht8GQ

Comment: It's stuck in the loop; the GUI can't respond while in there. You are trying to cram console style linear code into a non-linear winforms application; a square peg into a round hole.  Instead, put your logic into a different sub, without the loop, that is called from the button handler.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Idle_Mind. You took the idea of a console game and ported it to winforms. That is perfectly fine, but you have to change the behavior of the application.

You would not ask the user for north, east, south, west but put buttons on top, left, down, right of your text field, and the event handlers of those buttons would then call logic on an object that e.g. has a property CurrentRoom that returns a room object which has a function `Go(direction As Direction)` and which then would return the next room object etc.